# EMR Serverless Spark Executors Timeout

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, emr-serverless

I have an EMR Serverless application that is getting stuck in executions timeouts for some reason. I have tested all s3 connections and it's working. The problem is happening during the execution of a query in spark tables.

The EMR version is: emr-6.7.0
The same job was abble to run on spark 3.1.1 version in k8s, maybe it's something related to version.

My spark session setup:

```
spark = (SparkSession.builder
         .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload", True)
         .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
         .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
         .config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
         .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1000")
         .config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true")
         .config("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled", "true")
         .config("spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes", "268435456")
         .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0")
         .config("spark.jars.packages", "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17")
         .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
         )
```

Driver log:

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/hadoop/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars
org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-b943cb44-441b-41b2-8ea1-c44496d2e550;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;3.2.0 in central
    found com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-bundle;1.11.375 in central
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.0/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;3.2.0!hadoop-aws.jar (20ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.375/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-bundle;1.11.375!aws-java-sdk-bundle.jar (960ms)
:: resolution report :: resolve 823ms :: artifacts dl 984ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-bundle;1.11.375 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;3.2.0 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   2   |   2   |   2   |   0   ||   2   |   2   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-b943cb44-441b-41b2-8ea1-c44496d2e550
    confs: [default]
    2 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (96887kB/80ms)
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.2.1-amzn-0
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: spark_segmentacao_caminhoneiros.py
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 4, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 14336, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpus at 4 tasks per executor
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/09/28 12:28:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication enabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 33303.
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-22f8e599-8bdc-4d65-a5c1-f9ab0bf5f01c
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 7.3 GiB
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SubResultCacheManager: Sub-result caches are disabled.
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO log: Logging initialized @8694ms to org.sparkproject.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO Server: jetty-9.4.43.v20210629; built: 2021-06-30T11:07:22.254Z; git: 526006ecfa3af7f1a27ef3a288e2bef7ea9dd7e8; jvm 1.8.0_342-b07
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO Server: Started @8797ms
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@2f0a0570{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1afe3ab7{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4318eaf1{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@31a7233b{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2db507b1{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@69ab6402{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@34f8396d{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@e3b0050{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e50a487{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@58d7e2db{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@73151501{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1a9ef059{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7e3d6570{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2e69b2c6{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40447208{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2431cfcb{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2e719959{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2ec050df{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@72d76b63{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7670552a{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1b0420c5{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@60bcb746{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6aea04c3{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@476f8bfa{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@652b8b55{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4d0d77ae{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:4040
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/tmp/spark-bc069368-d1ab-4d24-a4e3-f7a8634a3d52/uber-jars-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar at spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/uber-jars-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar at spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar at spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/tmp/spark-bc069368-d1ab-4d24-a4e3-f7a8634a3d52/varname.zip at spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/varname.zip with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO Utils: Copying /tmp/spark-bc069368-d1ab-4d24-a4e3-f7a8634a3d52/varname.zip to /tmp/spark-8a3a402d-55f0-4a4f-a4d1-ce318ac97655/userFiles-5a356bf3-38d4-424a-a72e-036ab107a80c/varname.zip
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:///home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar at spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO Utils: Copying /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar to /tmp/spark-8a3a402d-55f0-4a4f-a4d1-ce318ac97655/userFiles-5a356bf3-38d4-424a-a72e-036ab107a80c/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:///home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar at spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:28:26 INFO Utils: Copying /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar to /tmp/spark-8a3a402d-55f0-4a4f-a4d1-ce318ac97655/userFiles-5a356bf3-38d4-424a-a72e-036ab107a80c/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO Utils: Using initial executors = 3, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO ExecutorContainerAllocator: Set total expected execs to {0=3}
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 34635.
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:34635
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9], 34635, None)
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:34635 with 7.3 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9], 34635, None)
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9], 34635, None)
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9], 34635, None)
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO ExecutorContainerAllocator: Going to request 3 executors for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 3 already provisioned: 0.
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@74d28ce8{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO DefaultEmrServerlessRMClient: Creating containers with container role SPARK_EXECUTOR and keys: Set(1, 2, 3)
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO SingleEventLogFileWriter: Logging events to file:/var/log/spark/apps/00f4ck9kasg9e001.inprogress
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO Utils: Using initial executors = 3, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
22/09/28 12:28:27 WARN ExecutorAllocationManager: Dynamic allocation without a shuffle service is an experimental feature.
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO ExecutorContainerAllocator: Set total expected execs to {0=3}
22/09/28 12:28:27 INFO DefaultEmrServerlessRMClient: Containers created with container role SPARK_EXECUTOR. key to container id map: Map(2 -> b6c1c208-d6ae-f116-456c-a70e62753a3e, 1 -> eec1c208-d6a4-a06f-416f-d3542eb67229, 3 -> 20c1c208-d6b9-a01b-3d7d-4e5d1ab9d5ee)
22/09/28 12:28:32 INFO EmrServerlessClusterSchedulerBackend$EmrServerlessDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (2600:1f18:1837:bf02:751c:4b79:c015:1299:36790) with ID 2,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/09/28 12:28:32 INFO ExecutorMonitor: New executor 2 has registered (new total is 1)
22/09/28 12:28:32 INFO EmrServerlessClusterSchedulerBackend$EmrServerlessDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (2600:1f18:1837:bf02:5500:4064:5306:1a1b:54690) with ID 3,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/09/28 12:28:32 INFO ExecutorMonitor: New executor 3 has registered (new total is 2)
22/09/28 12:28:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:751c:4b79:c015:1299]:37079 with 7.9 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:751c:4b79:c015:1299], 37079, None)
22/09/28 12:28:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:5500:4064:5306:1a1b]:40287 with 7.9 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(3, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:5500:4064:5306:1a1b], 40287, None)
22/09/28 12:28:57 INFO EmrServerlessClusterSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000000000(ns)
22/09/28 12:28:57 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
22/09/28 12:28:57 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/home/hadoop/spark-warehouse'.
22/09/28 12:28:57 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7ab37b5f{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:57 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3223cfe1{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:57 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@76ac5ba2{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:57 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@105afb2a{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:57 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7877cc29{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
22/09/28 12:28:57 WARN SQLConf: The SQL config 'spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite' has been deprecated in Spark v3.2 and may be removed in the future. Use 'spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite' instead.
22/09/28 12:28:57 WARN SQLConf: The SQL config 'spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite' has been deprecated in Spark v3.2 and may be removed in the future. Use 'spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite' instead.
22/09/28 12:28:58 WARN SQLConf: The SQL config 'spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite' has been deprecated in Spark v3.2 and may be removed in the future. Use 'spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite' instead.
22/09/28 12:28:58 WARN MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
22/09/28 12:29:08 WARN package: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields'.
22/09/28 12:29:11 WARN SQLConf: The SQL config 'spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite' has been deprecated in Spark v3.2 and may be removed in the future. Use 'spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite' instead.
22/09/28 12:29:12 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.jdbc.timeout does not exist
22/09/28 12:29:12 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.retries.wait does not exist
22/09/28 12:29:16 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 2.3.0
22/09/28 12:29:16 WARN ObjectStore: setMetaStoreSchemaVersion called but recording version is disabled: version = 2.3.0, comment = Set by MetaStore UNKNOWN@10.95.30.61
22/09/28 12:29:16 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
22/09/28 12:29:17 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
22/09/28 12:36:26 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 26 with no recent heartbeats: 176265 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
22/09/28 12:39:26 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 3 with no recent heartbeats: 161128 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
22/09/28 12:39:26 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 3 on [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:5500:4064:5306:1a1b]: Executor heartbeat timed out after 161128 ms
22/09/28 12:39:26 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 26.0 (TID 1321) ([2600:1f18:1837:bf02:5500:4064:5306:1a1b] executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 161128 ms
```

Executor 26 logs:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 30@ip-10-95-26-159.ec2.internal
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/09/28 12:32:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication enabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9:33303 after 134 ms (55 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication enabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9:33303 after 5 ms (3 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-37e26761-99b2-4b65-94b7-4df6bf9905ea
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 7.9 GiB
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO SubResultCacheManager: Sub-result caches are disabled.
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.executor.
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID 26 on host [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:4600:e58e:ddf0:59df]
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 43365.
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:4600:e58e:ddf0:59df]:43365
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(26, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:4600:e58e:ddf0:59df], 43365, None)
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(26, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:4600:e58e:ddf0:59df], 43365, None)
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(26, [2600:1f18:1837:bf02:4600:e58e:ddf0:59df], 43365, None)
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9:33303 after 5 ms (3 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/09/28 12:32:26 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar to /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/fetchFileTemp1966826708488121221.tmp
22/09/28 12:32:27 INFO PlatformInfo: Unable to read clusterId from http://localhost:8321/configuration, trying extra instance data file: /var/lib/instance-controller/extraInstanceData.json
22/09/28 12:32:27 INFO PlatformInfo: Unable to read clusterId from /var/lib/instance-controller/extraInstanceData.json, trying EMR job-flow data file: /var/lib/info/job-flow.json
22/09/28 12:32:27 INFO PlatformInfo: Unable to read clusterId from /var/lib/info/job-flow.json, out of places to look
22/09/28 12:32:27 INFO DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory: Unable to create provider using constructor: DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain(java.net.URI, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
22/09/28 12:32:27 INFO ClientConfigurationFactory: Set initial getObject socket timeout to 2000 ms.
22/09/28 12:32:27 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: eagerFSInit: Eagerly initialized FileSystem at s3://does/not/exist in 1165 ms
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Utils: Copying /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/-1178519531664368105728_cache to /home/hadoop/./com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/varname.zip with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/varname.zip to /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/fetchFileTemp6614333905641289896.tmp
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Utils: Copying /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/-9167713411664368105728_cache to /home/hadoop/./varname.zip
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/files/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar to /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/fetchFileTemp4499682470385493011.tmp
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Utils: Copying /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/8736416361664368105728_cache to /home/hadoop/./org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/uber-jars-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:32:29 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/uber-jars-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/fetchFileTemp8998725698456889956.tmp
22/09/28 12:32:32 INFO Utils: Copying /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/-13557803421664368105728_cache to /home/hadoop/./uber-jars-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
22/09/28 12:32:32 INFO Executor: Adding file:/home/hadoop/./uber-jars-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to class loader
22/09/28 12:32:32 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:32:32 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar to /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/fetchFileTemp2300668029112739372.tmp
22/09/28 12:32:35 INFO Utils: /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/-1974999101664368105728_cache has been previously copied to /home/hadoop/./com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar
22/09/28 12:32:35 INFO Executor: Adding file:/home/hadoop/./com.amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar to class loader
22/09/28 12:32:35 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar with timestamp 1664368105728
22/09/28 12:32:35 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://[2600:1f18:1837:bf02:a556:ccd:86d7:a6c9]:33303/jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar to /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/fetchFileTemp8882461784948851806.tmp
22/09/28 12:32:35 INFO Utils: /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934/14299127831664368105728_cache has been previously copied to /home/hadoop/./org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
22/09/28 12:32:35 INFO Executor: Adding file:/home/hadoop/./org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar to class loader
22/09/28 12:33:37 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
22/09/28 12:33:37 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/09/28 12:33:37 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/09/28 12:33:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/09/28 12:33:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-91625202-5612-49eb-b355-3f637abe1934
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a mysql database? I see the "mysql-connector" in your spark.jars - does your EMR Serverless application have access to the mysql endpoint? Also, you don't need to specify "hadoop-aws" in your jars, that's automatically included.

Comment: Yes, it has a mysql connection that is working well. I'm still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your log provided, you didn't config your executor memory when you create EMR application?

`ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM` this error only indicates that your executor was killed but didn't mention about the reason behind. As your log shows that your executor was killed during the data fetching but not at the beginning of your data fetching or executor initialization, I suspect your executor was killed due to out of memory (OOM). Try to increase your executor memory when you create your EMR application. On the other hand, you can check if there is any data skew in your job since it might trigger OOM too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a serverless environment (skip the hudi bit if not using hudi), make sure the following are set in your Spark configuration for faster, more shuffled processing:

```html
"hoodie.index.type": "GLOBAL_BLOOM",  # Ensure unique by record key
"hoodie.insert.shuffle.parallelism": "100",
"hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism": "100",
"hoodie.delete.shuffle.parallelism": "100",
"hoodie.bulkinsert.shuffle.parallelism": "100",
"hoodie.memory.merge.max.size": "2004857600000"
```

And in the spark submit paramaters:

```html
"sparkSubmit": {
    "entryPoint": f"s3://{config['bucket_name']}/scripts/my_spark_script.py",
    "entryPointArguments": [],
    "sparkSubmitParameters": f"\
        --conf spark.jars=/usr/lib/hudi/hudi-spark-bundle.jar \
        --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
        --conf spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.client.factory.class=com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory \
        --conf spark.emr-serverless.driver.disk=100G \
        --conf spark.emr-serverless.executor.disk=100G \
        --conf spark.executor.memory=26G \
        --conf spark.driver.memory=26G"
}
```